# Ajax Request doesn't update only the logged in user

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax Request which is called every minute, and updates the logged in user's last activity DateTime in the database. My problem is that it updates multiple users and it should update only the one, who is logged in.

When I call the function using a link, it works well (updates only the logged in), but when the Ajax Request is called updates multiple users.

Some idea, what's wrong or why it is doing that?

**Ajax request called every minute if the user is online**

```
function update_user_activity() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updateActivity',
        method: 'post',
        cache: false,

    });

    <?php
    use App\Session;
    if (Session::exist('id')) :
    ?>
    setInterval(function () {
        update_user_activity();
    },60 * 1 * 1000);
    <?php endif; ?>
}
```

**Method which updates the last activity datetime**

```
public function updateActivity() {
    if (!$this->authenticator->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->redirect('signin');
    }
    $params = [
        'last_activity' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa'))),
        'id' => Session::get('details_id')
    ];
    $this->userDetails->patch($params);
}
```

The session has only on `details_id`, so I don't understand why is updating another user too.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have when you print Session::get('details_id'), just before calling $this->userDetails->patch($params); ? Is it just one id or multiple ? You will then have a more precise idea of where your problem comes from.

Comment: @Cedric string(2) "11" which is a row inside UserDetails table